# Built-in module enabled at kernel configuration is missing

Tags: debian, kernel, kernel-modules

I configured a debian kernel 5.10.57 to add the HSR/PRP module. I enabled it as built-in `<*>`. Then i compiled and installed the kernel using `make deb-pkg` and `dpkg -i *.deb` respectively.

The new kernel is running.

```
debian@debian:~$ uname -r
5.10.57
```

The HSR/PRP module path is in the builtin.modules file :

```
debian@debian:~$ cat /lib/modules/5.10.57/modules.builtin |grep hsr
kernel/net/hsr/hsr.ko
```

But the hsr directory (and the .ko file) does not exist.

```
debian@debian:~$ ls /lib/modules/5.10.57/kernel/net/ |grep hsr
debian@debian:~$
```

So the module is not loaded.

```
debian@debian:~$ lsmod |grep hsr
debian@debian:~$
```

In the `/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/` folder, containing the kernel I compiled, the hsr configuration files are all here.

```
debian@debian:~$ ls /usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr/
hsr_debugfs.c  hsr_forward.c   hsr_framereg.h  hsr_netlink.c  hsr_slave.h
hsr_device.c   hsr_forward.h   hsr_main.c      hsr_netlink.h  Kconfig
hsr_device.h   hsr_framereg.c  hsr_main.h      hsr_slave.c    Makefile
debian@debian:~$
```

I tried a few commands to build the `.ko` file but nothing worked.

```
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$ make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$ make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$ make modules
make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$ make modules_install
make: *** No rule to make target 'modules_install'.  Stop.
```

If you want to know what is in the Makefile :

```
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$ cat Makefile
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
#
# Makefile for HSR
#

obj-$(CONFIG_HSR)       += hsr.o

hsr-y                   := hsr_main.o hsr_framereg.o hsr_device.o \
                           hsr_netlink.o hsr_slave.o hsr_forward.o
hsr-$(CONFIG_DEBUG_FS) += hsr_debugfs.o
debian@debian:/usr/src/linux-5.10.57/net/hsr$
```

Here are my questions :

- Does a builtin module need a .ko file to be in the path required by the `/lib/modules/5.10.57/modules.builtin` file  to be loaded ?
- If yes, how can I generate or find the `hsr.ko` file I need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you configured the driver as built-in, rather than a module (`<M>` in  the kernel configuration), it is part of the kernel binary (`bzImage` etc.). It will always be “loaded” whenever that particular kernel binary is booted.

You won’t see it as a separate `.ko` file, nor will you be able to force the `.ko` file to be built.